# Marginalization and integration of pdfs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have to r.v. $X_0$ and $X_1$ and $Y$.
Is the following integration correct
\begin{align*}
&\int\int \int x_0 x_1  f_{X_0|Y}(x_0|y)f_{X_1|Y}(x_1|y) f_{Y}(y) dx_0 dx_1 dy\\
&=\int \int x_0 x_1  f_{X_0}(x_0)f_{X_1}(x_1) dx_0 dx_1
\end{align*}
where in the last inequality I marginalized with respect to $Y$. Is this marginalization step correct?

The above is definitely true if $f_{X_0,X_1,Y}(x_0,x_1,y)$ factors as $f_{X_0,X_1,Y}(x_0,x_1,y)=f_Y f_{X_0|Y} f_{X_1|Y}$

Comment: The pdf is general just $f_{X_0,X_1,Y}$. I am interested if what I did in the integration is correct?